# Disable reading pane in Outlook for Junk Email folder only?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Is there a way to disable showing the reading pane when viewing the Junk Email folder but still have it enabled for my Inbox?

I'm using Microsoft Outlook for Office 365 MSO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, whether the reading pane is turned on or off is set separately for each folder. See the discussion here: [Outlook Reading Pane -- Disable for All Folders](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/909ff763-82eb-44b5-bca2-94084d3cc35a/outlook-reading-pane-disable-for-all-folders?forum=outlook)

So for your scenario, you can turn off the reading pane for Junk email folder only.This won't affect other folders.

Comment: For reference, this is done by selecting the Junk Email folder, clicking "View" at the top, then clicking Reading Pane > Off.